# Change SVG icon color using inline css

Tags: html, css

I am fairly new to SVG but how can I display a SVG icon and change its color using inline CSS? For example, if I wanted to change the color of example.svg to #FFF000 how would I do that?

I tried searching online but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

collinksmith did answer your question but didn't explain that you cannot change the colour of a .svg file with CSS. You need to add the SVG inline then you can apply CSS to it.

Comment: You can edit that answer if you want to add something or describe completely here

Comment: ^^^^^This is the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `fill` property of the svg's `path`. Assuming an svg html element, with a class set on the svg element itself:

```
.class-name path {
  fill: red;
}
```

**EDIT** Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/4447zb7o/

**EDIT 2** To set the css inline, change the `style` attribute of the `path` element inside the svg:

```
<svg class="my-svg" height="210" width="400">
  <path style="fill: green" d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
</svg>
```

Comment: the svg element can be within an img tag? for example:

.test path {
  fill: red;
}
<img class="test" src="https://abs.twimg.com/a/1450471907/img/t1/favicon.svg">

Comment: @lancey if SVG is inside an img or object or iframe  tag, then you cannot reach it with CSS since it is another document/file/uri

Comment: gotcha, so im confused on how do you set the svg file path if you have a svg icon stored in a folder within a server.

Comment: @lancey Adding to what GCyrillus said, see the section "The problem with both <img> and background-image" [here](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/)

Comment: Thanks for the example but the example you gave is for creating a shape path rather than grabbing an image from svgimages/example.svg, displaying it and then change it colors. I hope that makes sense.